# td element is too wide if picture in it

Tags: html, css

I developing a Pokedex right now, but I have a problem with the images.

The move rows are written like this:

```
<tr class=".$rowClass."><td><img src='../img/types/".strtolower($getChargedMove['type']).".png' width=10% style='display: block;' /></td><td> ".$getChargedMove['name']."</td><td>".$power."</td><td>".round($dps,2)." </td><td>".$getChargedMove['energy_delta']."</td><td>".$moveTime."</td></tr>
```

But my problem is that in this situation the image `<td>` is way too much wide then it should:
[image]

How to fix this? I only want to it be as wide as the type symbol.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Remove the width="10%" from the <td> tag. Either you set a fixed width for all the tds, or you set it in pixel.

Comment: Also check the width of the column in the header row (if any). Would be great if you could provide the code of your entire table, plus CSS (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, the width value must be in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to give the `<td>` Element which contains the image a width.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be possibly due to the `width=10%` attribute set to the `img` element.

```
<img src='../img/types/".strtolower($getChargedMove['type']).".png' width=10% style='display: block;' />
```

The possible solution to this is to set the desired `img` width in pixels.

e.g.,

> `width = 10`